# Solve a optimization problem with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Trying to solve next issue $$ \begin{cases} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i(ln_{x_i} - c_i)  - min
\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1
  \end{cases}$$
where
$$
x_i, c_i \in R^n, c_i = const > 0  \forall i
$$

I tried Lagrange method:

$$
L(x,\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i(ln_{x_i} - c_i) + \lambda(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - 1)
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
\ln x_i =c_i-(1+\lambda)
\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - 1 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
so,
$$
x_i = e^{c_i - (1+\lambda)} 
$$
and $\lambda$ gets from equation
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n e^{c_i - (1+\lambda)} = 1
$$
Second derivative matrix is positive defined for all $x_i >0$ therefore this point is the solution.

**Could you suggest me how to solve equation for $\lambda$ ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $\sum_{i=1}^n e^{c_i - (1+\lambda)} = 1$ we get $\frac{1}{e^{1+ \lambda}}\sum_{i=1}^n e^{c_i}=1$ thus $e^{1+ \lambda}=\sum_{i=1}^n e^{c_i}$, therefore

$$1 +\lambda= \ln (\sum_{i=1}^n e^{c_i}).$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!